# Multiple tables of contents in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I would like to make a LaTeX document with two tables of contents, like:

> Contents overview
>
> - 1 - Introduction
> - 2 - Solution
>
> Detailed contents
>
> - 1 - Introduction
>
>   - 1.1 - The problem
>   - 1.2 - Why?
> - 2 - Solution
>
>   - 2.1 - Phase A
>   - 2.2 - Phase B

I tried with

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
```

but this only displays the first table of contents as required. The second table of contents is empty...
(The second table of contents is actually empty even without the two `\setcounter` lines.)

(A related question: how to change the title of the table of contents (to something different than the default Contents)?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the [shorttoc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shorttoc/) package?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the ToC with \renewcommand,

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My New Table Of Contents}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My New Table of Contents}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newpage
\section{Section a}
Some a text.
\subsection{Subsection b}
Some b text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection c}
Some c text.

\newpage
\section{Section d}
Some d text.
\subsection{Subsection e}
Some e text.

\end{document}
```

I have customized the look of the \maketitle command using \renewcommand, so you might want to look into renewing \tableofcontents.

Comment: It does not seem to change the title of the table of contents. I don't know how to use that...

Comment: You put the command inside your preamble. I'll edit-in an example.